# How do you run your tests?

Tags: c#, testing, build, automation, automated-tests

When I was on my industrial year as part of my degree, I ran our FV tests using JUnit inside of Ant (scheduled build system).

I am wondering:

1. Is this the "norm"?
2. Are there any other ways people run there tests?

Please note this is regarding how people in large teams within organisations (test engineers) run there tests.

Edit: I used eclipse with IBM RTC.

Thanks.

Comment: This question seems better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Continuous Integration (CI). With tools like Jenkins, Hudson, TeamCity, you check in your code, then at a build server, your code is tested and reported for coverage and test results etc.

Also before any deployment your tests should run and pass with some criteria you define.

You can have unit tests, acceptance tests, end to end test, all these can be automated at a build server.

For large/enterprise applications, you should definitely use CI.

Comment: I understand the above but I am looking more at the internals i.e. is it considered normal to run tests inside Ant / .csproj.

I should have probably mentioned we used Eclipse with IBM RTC.

Comment: Well, yes, of course. If you use ant, maven or msbuild, you need to tell it to run tests.